# How should I interpret $y-x$ in this context?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, axioms

I asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580530/the-concept-of-negative-numbers-in-the-4th-field-axiom). I am meticulously working my way trough Mathematical Analysis by Apostol. I am reading about axioms, specifically axiom 4:

- Given any 2 real numbers $x$ and $y$, there exists a real number $z$ such that $x + z = y$. This $z$ is denoted by $y - x$; the number $x
     - x$ is denoted by $0$. (It can be proved that $0$ is independent of $x$.)  We write $-x$ for $0 - x$ and call $-x$ the negative of $x$.

In the related question, it was concluded that $y-x$ should not be interpreted as $y + (-x)$; it can be proven to be such, but it does not follow directly from the axiom.

The problem is that the only operators we have explicitly assumed in the book are addition and multiplication.

So my question is, I'm supposed to treat the $"-"$ like a meaningless symbol for now (just a part of the symbol representing $z$), or am I supposed to take it as subtraction but the author just didn't bother to explicitly assume subtraction? Am I allowed to break it down and write $y + y - x = 2y - x$? (I think I would probably need to prove that $x + x = 2x$ before anything though.) Or is there another way I should think about it?

The axioms that were given before this were the associative, commutative, and distributive laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should interpret $y-x$ as ***just a whole symbol*** when representing $z$ in the axiom 4. The first sentence does not define $-x$, the last sentence does instead.

What immediately follows from the first sentence is that there exists a real number $z$ such that $x+z=x$. We *symbolically* denote this $z$ by $x-x$, or alternatively $0(x)$. Notice that I didn't omit "$(x)$" for $0$. What is special about zero is that $0(x)$ *is independent of* $x$, that is, $0(x)=0(y)$ for $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. This follows from commutative laws and associative laws of addition, and uniquness of $0(x+y)$ (which is guaranteed in the first sentence of the axiom 4). Given this, we can safely denote $0(x)$ simply by $0$, and it immediately follows from the first sentence that there exists a real number $w$ such that $x+w=0$. While a 'straightforward' notation of $w$ is $0-x$, we denote it by $-x$ in practice. Thus the negative of $x$ is finally defined, and we can easily check that $y-x$ defined in the first sentence coincides with $y+(-x)$.

What the discussion above tells us is that $x+(-x)=0$ is trivial; it is the definition of $-x$! Note that we don't have to prove the uniquness of $-x$, because it is guaranteed by the first sentence of the axiom 4. Also, you can show that $y+(y-x)=(y+y)-x$ without knowledge of $y-x=y+(-x)$ (if you have any difficulty in proving this, please let me know).

*Appendix: Proof of the uniqueness of zero*

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Associative laws of addition and definition of $0(x)$ indicate $$(x+y)+0(y)=x+(y+0(y))=x+y.$$ Commutative laws of addition is additionally required to show that $$(x+y)+0(x)=x+(y+0(x))=x+(0(x)+y)=(x+0(x))+y=x+y.$$
After all, we obtain $(x+y)+0(x)=x+y$ and $(x+y)+0(y)=x+y$, and uniqueness of $0(x+y)$ requires $0(x)=0(y)$.

Comment: I have a couple questions in regards to the first part of your answer. Claimed that it can be shown that $0x=0y$. To prove this, is it sufficient to say that  $y-y=x-x$, then $y(1-1)=x(1-1)$, $0y=0x$? To prove that $x-x=0x$, don't we need another axiom (or proof) that says that $x \cdot 1 = x$?

Comment: Also, I believe I was able to prove that $y+(y-x)=(y+y)-x$. From sentence 1 we have $x + (y-x) = y$. We add $y$ to both sides, and with associativity regroup as: $x+(y+(y-x)) = y+y$. If we take $a=x, c=(y+(y-x)), b = y+y$, from sentence 1 we have $c=b-a$, or  $y+(y-x) (y+y)-x$ Is there a better way to prove this? Also, I am a bit concerned because in getting this proof I kind of "cheated". I mean because I already knew the answer I assumed it was true (since I knew it was) and worked backwards to try to find a true statement, from which I could work forwards in my proof above

Comment: In the first part of my answer, I didn't mean to prove $0\cdot x=0\cdot y$. What we have to be careful is that, it is _not_ ruled out directly from the definition that a real number $z$ (that I denoted by $0(x)$) such that $x+z=x$ and $z^{\prime}$ (that I denoted by $0(y)$) such that $y+z^{\prime}=y$ is different for $x\ne y$. However, we can prove that this is not the case, as I showed in the Appendix. This is what I claimed in the 4th sentence of the second paragraph.

Comment: FYI (in reply to your first comment): We can derive $0\cdot x=0$ from a distributive law and uniqueness of $0$; notice that $(x+0)\cdot y=x\cdot y+0\cdot y$ and $(x+0)\cdot y=x\cdot y$. More generally, we can also show that $x\cdot(y-z)=x\cdot y-x\cdot z$ in a similar manner (if you find it difficult to prove, please let me know), although we should note that this is _not_ a direct consequence of the distributive law.

Comment: I think your proof of $y+(y-x)=(y+y)-x$ is fine, but it might be more 'natural' to start from LHS or RHS of the formula you would like to prove/disprove. Here is an example: Start from  LHS $y+(y-x)$. Basic strategy is to eliminate $-$ by adding an appropriate term. That is, $y+(x+(y-x))=y+y$, and associative laws and commutative law lead us to $x+(y+(y-x))=y+y$. Thus, $y+(y-x)$ satisfies the definition of $(y+y)-x$, and the uniqueness of $(y+y)-x$ guarantees $y-(y-x)=(y+y)-x$.

Comment: My apologies, I haven't looked at the appendix proof yet because I would like to try my hand at everything before I look at the answer. Are you saying that when it says in axiom 4 "we denote $x-x$ by $0$", that $0$ is not necessarily the  integer between $-1$ and $1$, but rather a possible variable? If this is the case and we do prove zero is a constant wouldn't it be extremely difficult to prove where zero's place on the number line is?

Comment: Also, could you tell me if you would consider the following a valid proof of the uniqueness of zero? We have $y + 0 = y$ --> $y + (x-x) = y$ --> $x-x=y-y$

Comment: I will make some more separate questions soon because I would love to give you more credit for your awesome help and answers here. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: EDIT I believe now I see that my proof above is circular, the $0$ in $y+o=y$ is not required to be the same as the $0$ that is represented by $x-x$ tough I'm not sure I understand everything completely. It's often confusing because clearly there are more axioms implied that the 4 gives (i.e. if a=b, then a+c=b+c is not explicitly given), and I'm not sure which ones are and aren't assumed. I am very curious though haha how you seem to quickly find proofs for everything. I think finding the right starting identity is to manipulate is the most important part, but also the hardest.

Comment: I have a slight idea on how to find the right starting place (mostly by trying to work backwards to a true identity, and then presenting the proof as fowards), but most of the time it is just a shot in the dark. This is what I meant when I mentioned that I felt like I was "cheating"

Comment: Just a quick reply to some specific comments (because I see a warning not to extend discussion in comments): In this context, $0$ is just a short abbreveation of $x-x$, not an integer between $-1$ and $1$. Note that we cannot discuss about the "place on the number line" until we define an order between two real numbers, which will be done in Sect. 1.3 on Apostol's textbook. And as you noticed, your 'proof' of the uniqueness of zero is circular, because you implicitly assume that zero is unique for a transformation between the first line and second line.

Comment: If you are interested in continuing the discussion, I have posted another question here where I attempted to prove the uniqueness of 0 (I know you posted a proof already but I wanted to try one myself)  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584906/is-my-proof-of-the-uniqueness-of-0-correct

Comment: May I ask what was your though process/motivation on finding a way to prove the uniqueness of zero? There are a thousand different places where you could start, how did you know to start where you did?

Comment: My motivation of the proof is based on "proof by contradiction". One obvious thing is that if uniqueness of zero doesn't hold, $(x=)x+0(x)\ne x+0(y)$ for $y\ne x$ in general. I found that if I added $y$ to both hands of the formula, a strange situation would happen ($x+y\ne x+y$?). However, I didn't prefer to accept "proof by contradiction" as a final conclusion, so I considered further. I was aware that at least two "zeros" ($0(x)$ and $0(y)$) should appear in the proof. Knowing $x+0(x)=x$ and $y+0(y)=y$, I decided that playing with $x+y$ is one of the benefitable choices. That is the story.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight!