# Are my proofs consistent/non-circular/correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, axioms

I am slowly working my way trough "Mathematical Analysis" by Apostol, and I decided to try my hand at a few proofs. (I asked related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580530/the-concept-of-negative-numbers-in-the-4th-field-axiom) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580808/how-should-i-interpret-y-x-in-this-context), so some of the work here might be from the answers there)

So far we are only given the axioms:

**Axiom 1:**
*Commutative Laws*

$x+y = y + x$ , $xy=yx$

**Axiom 2:** *Associative Laws*

$x+(y+x) = (x+y)+z$ , $x(yz) = (xy)z$

**Axiom 3**
*Distributive Law*

$x(y+z)=xy+yz$

**Axiom 4**

*Given any two real numbers x and y, there exists a real number z such that x + z = y. This z is denoted by y-x; the number x-x is denoted by 0. (It can be proved that 0 is independent of x.) We write -x for 0-x and call -x the negative of x*

---

**Proof 1**: $x + 0 = x$

From axiom 4, we are guaranteed a $z$ such that $x+z = x$.

That $z$ is equal to $x-x=0$,

By substitution, $x + 0 = x$

Comments/concerns: I am not sure weather the $0$ in Axiom 4 is used just as a symbol/placeholder for $x-x$, or if it is actually meant to be the actual integer between $-1$ and $1$. That is, I am not sure if it's implied that $x-x$ evaluates to the same thing as $y-y$. I;m not sure that this is what is meant in axiom 4 by"it can be proved that $0$ is independent of $x$".

---

**Proof 2**: Proof that $0$ is a constant, not just a symbol placeholder

From proof 1, we have that

$y + 0 = y$

$y + (x-x) = y$

From axiom 4,

$x-x = y-y$

We know that $x-x = 0$, and therefore $y-y=0$ as well, so for the equation

$x+0=x$

$0$ is a constant and therefore the same for any $x$.

---

**Proof 3:** Axiom 4 can be reduced to: There is a number $-x$ such that $x + (-x) = 0$

So basically we are trying to prove that for any numbers $x$ and $y$, there exists $z$ such that $x + z = y$

Now we work backwards a little bit:

Take any two real numbers $x, z$, and let their sum be denoted by $y$

$x + y = z$

Add $(-x)$ to both sides:

$(x + z) + (-x) = y +(-x)$

Commutative Propriety

$(z+(-x)) + (-x) = y +(-x)$

Associative Propriety
$z+(x+(-x))=y+(-x)$

$x+(-x) = 0$

$z+0=y+(-x)$

$z = y+(-x)$

So $z$ exists as is denoted by $y+(-x)$

Comments/concerns: I just realized that this proof is circular, because it is dependent on proof 1 ($x+0=x$), which is dependent on axiom 4. So I don't know what to do with this. I am aware that in this version of axiom 4 we haven't introduced the subtraction operator, and even if we did we would need to prove that $y-x=y+(-x)$

Comment: Suggest that this be edited down to one specific question, preferably about one specific proof attempt.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I'll try to do that as soon as I have time (hopefully later today)